# how to find join tables and filter only results where it has all matches in an array?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a database that has a demo, allyTeam, and players tables. demo has many allyTeam. allyTeam has many players.

Say I want to find all demos where Alice and Bob are both players in the demo.

I have a query like this

```
        const foundDemos = await db.schema.demo.findAll({
            attributes: ["id"],
            include: [{
                model: db.schema.allyTeam,
                attributes: [],
                include: [{
                    model: db.schema.player,
                    attributes: [],
                    right: true,
                    where: {
                        userId: {
                            [Op.in]: userIds
                        }
                    }
                }],
                required: true
            }],
            group: ["Demo.id"],
        });
```

Say I have userIds = ["Bob", "Alice"];

This fetches demos where it has either Bob or Alice as a player. I want to modify the query so it only returns results where Bob AND Alice are both players in the demo (There can be more players in addition to them).